# Oracle - Function to return a query result based on parameter

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write an Oracle PL/SQL function that will return the given status_id of an application so I can archive data to a history table if the status_type returned is a specific value.

In the case of this example my status types are 'Approved', 'Pending' or 'Declined'

I have so far written this function so that I can run the method in an IF statement to check the current status type before archiving data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status(curr_id NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS this_type status_type;

BEGIN
    SELECT status_type 
    INTO this_type
    FROM status
    WHERE status_id LIKE curr_id;

    RETURN this_type;
END get_status;
```

And although it compiles I receive an error telling me that my PL/SQL statement has been ignored.
I am fairly new to Oracle so I am probably missing something straightforward here, could anyone give me any pointers as to where I am going wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance,
Alex.

Comment: Can you share the error please?

Comment: Sure: 
Error(2,31): PLS-00201: identifier 'STATUS_TYPE' must be declared AND
Error(5,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored -- As I understand it the line "this_type status_type" is setting the alias of this_type to status_type (which is a column in the status table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_status(curr_id NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2 
AS 
--%TYPE is used to declare variables with relation to the data type of a column 
--in an existing table 

this_type status.status_type%TYPE; --change is required here 

BEGIN
   SELECT status_type 
   INTO this_type
   FROM status
   WHERE status_id LIKE curr_id;

   RETURN this_type;
END get_status;
/
```

Comment: Note: 1. Using `like` condition without wildcard characters is equivalent to using equal sign. If there is no need to perform pattern matching, switch to simple equal sign; 2. Under different circumstances you may: a) hit the `not_data_found` error or b) `too_many_rows` error.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: you're correct,@Alex: plz keep this in mind